# docker image disappeared after build

Tags: docker

Below is my console log:

```
jy03154586@ubuntu:~/Works$ docker build -t ui .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  50.18MB
Step 1/9 : FROM node:carbon-alpine as build
 ---> adc4b0f5bc53
...
Step 9/9 : COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
 ---> 997cc6252b83
Successfully built 997cc6252b83
Successfully tagged ui:latest
jy03154586@ubuntu:~/Works$ docker images ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jy03154586@ubuntu:~/Works$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
jy03154586@ubuntu:~/Works$
```

I tried to build an angularjs application image, but where is the built image? It shows `successfully built`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave off the `ls` - that will filter the results. Just do `docker images`.

Answer (score 3):

docker image ls

docker images ls

docker images

Are all different commands

You want

docker image ls --filter reference=ui:latest

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

$ **docker images --help**

Usage:  docker images [OPTIONS] [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

List images

Options:
  -a, --all             Show all images (default hides intermediate images)
      --digests         Show digests
  -f, --filter filter   Filter output based on conditions provided
      --format string   Pretty-print images using a Go template
      --no-trunc        Don't truncate output
  -q, --quiet           Only show numeric IDs

**$ docker image ls --help**

Usage:  docker image ls [OPTIONS] [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

List images

Aliases:
  ls, images, list

Options:
  -a, --all             Show all images (default hides intermediate images)
      --digests         Show digests
  -f, --filter filter   Filter output based on conditions provided
      --format string   Pretty-print images using a Go template
      --no-trunc        Don't truncate output
  -q, --quiet           Only show numeric IDs

As you see docker image ls OR docker images OR docker image list does all the same thing.

> Helps to list all the images build on a docker host

List all images tagged as ui

**docker images ui**

Now if you are referring to "build" NAME in your [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) then it would be listed in your output for "docker images" with REPOSITORY ID as  & TAG as .